# How to check what exactly takes all the resources of the Mac?

Tags: macos

The problem is that today at some point my Mac started to work really slowly. All the apps work as if there are no resources at all, and each click takes 10 sec to respond.

I tried to restart the Mac a few times, and each time it started to work. Everything was ok, but then after 3 min, it became too slow again, even browsing in Chrome.

I know on Windows, there is Task Manager where you can see which exact process takes the most CPU, RAM etc, so this way (at least) it is possible to guess what it is possibly running on the background or something.

The question is - are there any diagnostic tools? Or any suggestions? Maybe some kind of recovery mode that I can use?

My mac spec:

[image]

and for now free space I have is: 326Gb available of 494Gb

Comment: "Even using Chrome". Chrome is not very efficient with CPU and RAM at the best of times! What Mac do you have, and how much RAM and free space on disk?

Comment: @benwiggy your are right, added in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple command to quickly find if something is abnormally
stucking your OS.
Open a `Terminal` or any other tool to be able to fire commands.

Then enter:

```
top -a -o cpu | grep stuck
```

let it run for one full minute, and then type <kbd>[ctl]</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> which will interrupt this command.
`top` is a command which permit to sort all processes running along any of
their ressources usage.
`grep` is a command to extract some lines based on a regular expression, here `stuck`,
which will catch all the processes blocked because they are
waiting for a blocked ressource ( CPU, memory, disk, message… ).

**If** this command doesn't show you any process stuck,
**then** you will have to use more advanced investigation tools,
**else** you will know which process blocks or slow your OS.

Answer (score 4):

As AVelj suggested in a since deleted comment, Activity Monitor, found in the Utilities folder in the Applications folder, is even more like the Windows Task Manager.

Activity Monitor is a standard Mac app.

---

The Unix `top` command will show statistics similar to Windows Task Manager.

Open the Terminal app (or your favorite terminal emulator) and key `top` at the command prompt. Type `q` to exit top and return to the prompt.